# Cannot resolve method "setCallbackData"

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Всем привет!

Пишу телеграм бота на java по гайду. Создаю inline клавиатуру, но не могу создать строку из-за ошибки **Cannot resolve method 'setCallbackData(java.lang.String)'**.

Прошу подсказать, как я могу прописать setCallbackData подобным образом или как можно обойти эту ошибку.

Заранее спасибо! Код приложил ниже.

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();
rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("Ошибка").setCallbackData("error_msg_text"));
```

Использую следующую библиотеку: `org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton`

Comment: Непонятно какую библиотеку вы используете, но поиск вывел на https://www.javatips.net/api/TelegramBots-master/telegrambots-meta/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/api/objects/replykeyboard/buttons/InlineKeyboardButton.java и там в классе InlineKeyboardButton есть метод setCallbackData... Уточните в вопросе библиотеку

Comment: @gil9red, добавил в вопрос название библиотеки.

Comment: Странно, но в текущей коде библиотеки нет такого метода: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/4882040822d202e146471d6196e3a40babbdb51a/telegrambots-meta/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/objects/replykeyboard/buttons/InlineKeyboardButton.java#L52 Возможно, там какая-то фабрика используется для создания объекта кнопки. Ага, нужно вот так делать: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/247274a5686b0f80959339f3912036ea37e8d2ff/telegrambots/src/test/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/test/BotApiMethodHelperFactory.java#L295

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрел в репозитории библиотеки [как создается объект InlineKeyboardButton](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/247274a5686b0f80959339f3912036ea37e8d2ff/telegrambots/src/test/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/test/BotApiMethodHelperFactory.java#L295) и получается так:

```
InlineKeyboardButton button = InlineKeyboardButton
    .builder()
    .text("Button1")
    .callbackData("Callback")
    .build();
```

В вашем случае будет так:

```
rowInline.add(InlineKeyboardButton.builder().text("Ошибка").callbackData("error_msg_text").build());
```

Comment: Добрый день! Написал как вы ответили, перестало подчёркивать красным цветом "callbackData". Даже кнопка адекватно отображается в телеграмме. Но когда я её нажимаю, у меня ничего не происходит. С чем это может быть связано? Если я верно понял, callbackData нужен для ответа пользователю на нажатие этой кнопки.

Comment: @Bogdan, добрый день! Ничего не происходит может по причине отсутствия обработчика этого callback-запроса. К сожалению, я не смогу вам помочь, т.к. не работал с этой библиотекой, да и пока готовил комментарий посмотрел в репозиторий и вопросов к ней осталось много ([у меня боты на питоне](https://github.com/gil9red?tab=repositories&q=telegram-bot&type=&language=&sort=)), поэтому рекомендую задать вопрос, приложив минимальный пример, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться желающим помочь :)